# MySQL Multiple tables JOIN , same column title

Tags: mysql

I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it. I'm trying but still no success.
I have 3 tables:

tour

```
id_tour    title
1          Discovery
2          Something
```

tour_to_country

```
id_tour    id_country
1          66
1          35
1          673
2          88
2          91
```

country

```
id_country title
1          Country_1
2          Country_2
...        ...
999        Country_999
```

I want to take the 2 tours from tour table, select all the countries inside each tour and display their name.

I want to select all the countries from each tour but the tour should be displayed once.

This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT tour.id_tour as tour_id, tour.title as tour_title, country.title as country_title, tour.* FROM tour 
        INNER JOIN tour_to_country ON tour.id_tour = tour_to_country.id_tour 
        INNER JOIN country ON country.id_country = tour_to_country.id_country
        GROUP BY tour.id_tour
```

It gives me the tours but I still don't know how to take all the countries in the same query.

[image: http://oi59.tinypic.com/1iby4l.jpg]

Comment: Edit your question with the results that you want for the desired data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GROUP_CONCAT should do the trick for you. You can specify ordering and separator. I assume this is what you wanted to achieve.

```
SELECT tour.id_tour as tour_id, tour.title as tour_title, GROUP_CONCAT(country.title ORDER BY country.title SEPARATOR ',') as country_title, tour.* FROM tour 
    INNER JOIN tour_to_country ON tour.id_tour = tour_to_country.id_tour 
    INNER JOIN country ON country.id_country = tour_to_country.id_country
    GROUP BY tour.id_tour
```